# Render Visualforcepage based on picklistValues

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I am trying to render a visualforce Page with the change in picklist values. The data I would like to render is the contact names in  a table. which changes depending on the sales Region i choose.

Controller

```apex
public class PhotoSchedulerController {

    public String salesRegionId { get; set; }
    public String ContactSalesRegion {get; set;}

    public PageReference salesRegionCoveredFilter() {
        String contacts =  [Select Id, Name, Sales_Regions_Covered__c from Contact where Sales_Regions_Covered__c = '03'].Sales_Regions_Covered__c;
        system.debug('sales region:' + contacts);

        return null;
    }

    public  List<SelectOption> getSalesRegionsCoveredValues() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult salesRegion = Contact.Sales_Regions_Covered__c.getDescribe();
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> salesRegions = salesRegion.getPicklistValues();
        for (Schema.Picklistentry entry : salesRegions) {
            options.add(new SelectOption(entry.getLabel(), entry.getValue()));
        }
        return options;
    }

    public List<String> getHeadDays() {
        List<String> formattedDays = new List<String>();
        List<DateTime> days = new List<DateTime>();
        DateTime currentDay = DateTime.now();
        for (Integer idx = 0; idx < 28; idx++) {
            days.add(currentDay + idx);
            system.debug('DAYS :' + days);
        }
        for (DateTime dt : days) {
            String formattedDay = dt.format('E');
            formattedDays.add(formattedDay);
        }
        return formattedDays;
    }

    public List<String> getHeadDates() {
        List<String> formattedDates = new List<String>();
        List<Date> dates = new List<Date>();
        Date currentDate = system.today();
        for (Integer idx = 0; idx < 28; idx++) {
            dates.add(currentDate + idx);
        }

        for (Date dt : dates) {
            String formattedDate = dt.format();
            formattedDates.add(formattedDate);

        }
        return formattedDates;
    }

    // retrieves the row wrapper containing the wrapped case headings
    public List<photographerRow> getDataRows() {
        List<String> scheduledDates = new List<String>();
        photographerRow pRow = new photographerRow();
        List<photographerRow> dataRows = new List<photographerRow>();
        for (Contact con : getContacts()) {
            pRow.photographer = con.Name;
            pRow.photographerId = con.Id;
            pRow.contacts.add(con);
        }
        for (Integer idx = 28; idx > 0; idx--) {
            pRow.subtotals.add(idx);
        }

        for (Case c : getCaseInfo()) {
            pRow.caseNumber = c.caseNumber;
            pRow.cases.add(c);
        }

        dataRows.add(pRow);
        return dataRows;
    }

    public class photographerRow {
        public String photographer {get; set;}
        public String photographerId {get; set;}
        public String caseNumber {get; set;}
        public List<Contact> contacts {get; set;}
        public List<Case> cases {get; set;}
        public List<Integer> subtotals {get; set;}
        public List<Integer> counts {get; set;}
        // constructor
        public PhotographerRow() {
            contacts = new List<Contact>();
            subtotals = new List<Integer>();
            counts = new List<Integer>();
            cases = new List <Case>();
        }
    }


    public List<Contact> getContacts() {
        List<Contact>contacts =  [Select Id, Name, Sales_Regions_Covered__c from Contact ];
        return contacts;
    }



    public List<Case> getCaseInfo() {
        List<String> contactsList = new List<String>();
        List<String> formattedDatesList = new List<String>();
        for (Contact c :  getContacts()) {
            contactsList.add(c.Name);
        }
        List<Date> dates = new List<Date>();
        Date currentDate = system.today();
        for (Integer idx = 0; idx < 28; idx++) {
            dates.add(currentDate + idx);
        }
        system.debug('Dates List :' + dates);
        system.debug('Contact LIst :' + contactsList);

        List<Case> cases = [Select id, CaseNumber, Scheduled_Date__c , Account.Owner.Name, Photographer_Contact__r.Name from Case where RecordType.DeveloperName In('Time_Booking', 'Media_Package', 'Photography')
                            and Scheduled_Date__c = :dates];
        system.debug('case queried:' + cases);
        return cases;
    }



    /* public Integer getCaseCount(){
        Integer caseCount;
        List<AggregateResult> groupedCases = [Select count(casenumber),Scheduled_Date__c, Photographer_Contact__r.Name from Case where RecordType.DeveloperName In('Time_Booking', 'Media_Package', 'Photography') and Scheduled_Date__c!=null group by Photographer_Contact__r.Name,Scheduled_Date__c];
        for (AggregateResult ar : groupedCases)  {
                caseCount = Integer.valueOf(ar.get('expr0'));
        }
    return caseCount;
    }*/
}
```

---

```
<apex:page controller="PhotoSchedulerController" tabstyle="Report" sidebar="false">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:outputPanel id="dataBlocks">
            <apex:sectionHeader title="Field Researcher Schedule for Region" />

            <apex:selectList value="{!contactSalesRegion}" size="1" multiselect="false">
                <b>Field Researcher Schedule for Region</b>
                <apex:selectOptions value="         {!SalesRegionsCoveredValues}"></apex:selectOptions>
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!salesRegionCoveredFilter}" reRender="dataBlock">
                    <apex:param name="salesRegionId" assignTo="{!salesRegionId}" value="{!SalesRegionsCoveredValues}"></apex:param>
                </apex:actionSupport>
            </apex:selectList>

            <apex:pageBlock>

                <table class="list" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="dataBlock">

                    <tr>
                        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;

                        <b>Scheduled Date</b>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>

                        <td>
                        </td>
                        <apex:repeat value="{!headDays}" var="days">
                            <th style="background-color:#00BFFF;">
                                {!days}
                            </th>
                        </apex:repeat>
                    </tr>

                    <tr class="headerRow  ">
                        <th style="background-color:#00BFFF;">Photographer: Full Name</th>

                        <apex:repeat value="{!headDates}" var="heading">
                            <th style="background-color:#00BFFF;" class="headerRow ">
                                {!heading}
                            </th>
                        </apex:repeat>
                    </tr>
                    <apex:repeat value="{!DataRows}" var="dRow">
                        <apex:repeat value="{!dRow.contacts}" var="photo">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="background-color:#d4dadc;">
                                    <a href="https://apartments--pre.cs20.my.salesforce.com/{!photo.Id}"> {!photo.Name} </a>
                                </td>

                                <apex:repeat value="{!dRow.cases}" var="count">

                                    <td>
                                        {!count.casenumber}
                                    </td>

                                </apex:repeat>

                            </tr>
                        </apex:repeat>

                    </apex:repeat>
                </table>
            </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you copied it 100%, but I did notice your outputPanel's ID is "dataBlocks", but your reRender attribute on the actionSupport is "dataBlock", which of course wouldn't work...